# how to call html in jsp by custome tag

Tags: java, struts

i want to transfer control from jsp  to html in my  Stuts2 product.
  and want to call the application level variable in html page;
  as example:

**index.jsp**

```
import  abc.tld file
<prifix:name=path/something.html

jsp ends here
```

now i want my application level variable in this html page.
could it be possible?
pls suggest? as i am making some product of my own purpose.in which i want to give cusotmization by using html only.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. You can't include dynamic content on an HTML file. Only on JSPs, or other template files (like freemarker).

Comment: actually  in my last company i got that a function as an example init() showpage(name of html,out) it is written in jsp page some variable has been added in collection on the same jsp.now the html accessing the variable of that collection which was addedd on jsp.how it is possible